# .net framework listview itemchecked event called every time item is added

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, listview

I am having a lot of trouble with some code because the `ListView.ItemChecked` Event is called every time an item is added to the listview. The only way I can manage to stop this is to check to see if the listview is in Focused when the even happens. But this feels really sloppy to me. Is there any other way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any other way to fix this?

One option would be to remove the handles clause and use the Add/RemoveHandler statements to control when the handler will handle the events.

Comment: I can remove the handler so that it is not called when an item is added, but how to I make it still call the even when it is actually checked?

Comment: use the AddHandler statement something like this,`AddHandler ListView1.ItemChecked AddressOf Listview1_ItemChecked` right after the item is added.

Comment: I was hoping for something that didn't require modification to every part of my code that added an item but I guess making a new sub for adding items would be the simplest way to solve this problem. Thanks.